# doas doesn't run a /usr/sbin binary

Tags: debian, command-line, environment-variables, path, doas

I'm using Debian/GNU/Linux Unstable,
and I was trying `doas` for the first time today, with the following simple config file:

```
$ doas cat /etc/doas.conf 
permit persist alx as root
```

While it worked for some time (I could for example run `doas apt-get update && doas apt-get upgrade`), the following failed:

```
alx@ady1:~$ doas gdisk /dev/sdb
doas: gdisk: command not found
```

Hmm, is it that `gdisk` is an `sbin` binary?  `apt-get` is a `bin` binary.  Maybe the `PATH` is wrong.  Let's check it:

```
$ sudo env | grep PATH
PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin
$ doas env | grep PATH
PATH=/bin:/sbin:/usr/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin
```

`doas` seems to know `sbin`, but there seems to be something reversed in the `PATH`.  Okay, where's `gdisk`?

```
alx@ady1:~$ sudo which gdisk
/usr/bin/which: this version of `which' is deprecated; use `command -v' in scripts instead.
/usr/sbin/gdisk
alx@ady1:~$ doas which gdisk
/usr/bin/which: this version of `which' is deprecated; use `command -v' in scripts instead.
/sbin/gdisk
```

`command -v` wouldn't work here, as it's a builtin, and won't work with `sudo` or `doas`, but let's ignore that warning (why would `which` be deprecated if there's no proper replacement?).

Hmm, they don't agree.  Let's see:

```
$ realpath /usr/sbin/gdisk 
/usr/sbin/gdisk
$ realpath /sbin/gdisk
/usr/sbin/gdisk
$ ls -l /sbin 
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 8 Nov 11 15:37 /sbin -> usr/sbin
```

Maybe it's due to the symlink that `doas` has trouble believing it should execute this binary?  Let's modify the `PATH` so that it first finds the real path:

```
$ doas PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin gdisk /dev/sdb
doas: PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin: command not found
```

Huh, this is weird.  Let's try using normal syntax (as opposed to `sudo` syntax; isn't this inconsistent or is it just me?):

```
$ PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin doas gdisk /dev/sdb
GPT fdisk (gdisk) version 1.0.8

Partition table scan:
  MBR: protective
  BSD: not present
  APM: not present
  GPT: present

Found valid GPT with protective MBR; using GPT.

Command (? for help): q
$
```

Okay, now it finds it.

What should be the correct fix for this problem?  Am I missing anything in the configuration?

Comment: That symbolic link seems broken. Shouldn't it go to `/usr/sbin` instead of `usr/sbin`. Also, you can only set a variable like `PATH` before a command like what you try to do if you have a shell, and you said yourself that you can't use `command -v` since it's a shell builtin.  Try `doas env PATH=... utility`.

Comment: @they Re: _"symbolic link seems broken"_: It's what comes with Debian by default (I didn't change it).  I guess it works because it's located in `/`, so anything relative to it is really not relative.

Comment: @they Re: _"Try `doas env PATH=... utility`"_: Yup, it also works.  I'm not so good with the `sh(1)`ell, so I ignore these details :).

Comment: Could you confirm that you have the same issue with other executables in `/sbin`?

Comment: @they Confirmed (with `fdisk` this time)

Comment: @they  It's weird:  I tried the following and it also works: `doas env PATH=/bin:/sbin:/usr/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin gdisk`  (this time, the `PATH` is the one from `doas env |grep PATH`.  The following succeeds: `doas env $(doas env | grep PATH) fdisk -l` while `doas fdisk -l` doesn't.  `doas env fdisk -l` also works.

Comment: @they, the symlink should be fine; without the leading slash it's just relative, just like as if you did `ln -s foo.txt bar.txt`. I would argue the relative link is more correct here, since it would still point to the right directory even if the whole tree was moved. (Even if it was mostly used as a chroot, someone might still modify it from the outside, and it would be good for `/path/to/chroot/bin` to be the same as `/path/to/chroot/usr/bin`)

Comment: @ilkkachu Thanks for that clarification.